# Packaging Apache Calcite CSV example into a JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, apache-calcite

The CSV example at 
   https://calcite.apache.org/docs/tutorial.html
shows how to access the CSV data using sqlline.

Does anyone know of any tutorial that show how to create a standalone JDBC driver from scratch for CSV example, so that it can be use for example using squirrelsql?

Comment: How did you configure the JDBC for squirrelsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to repackage anything as the standard artifacts contain a JDBC driver. You can see examples of valid JDBC connection strings [in the documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/tutorial.html).

For the CSV adapter, you might have a connection string like the following (substituting the appropriate path).

```
jdbc:calcite:schemaFactory=org.apache.calcite.adapter.csv.CsvSchemaFactory; schema.directory=/path/to/csv/files
```

Comment: How can I use it in a SQL client like Dbeaver?

Comment: @O.Sam That is a separate question and you should ask a new question.

Comment: i create an other tread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227079/apache-calcite-csv-adapter-sql-client can you please check it