# Apache Calcite CSV Adapter - SQL Client

Tags: apache-calcite

I am working on the development of a Connector interface with Elasticsearch (translate SQL to API DSL query syntax) .

I am starting with Apache Calcite CSV Adapter as a first step to test Calcite capabilities.
I followed the tutorial [https://calcite.apache.org/docs/tutorial.html](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/tutorial.html%C2%A0)

My question is how to use the JDBC connector (and which configuration) in a SQL client like Dbeaver or Squirrel... ?

Thanks

Edit:
This my configuration but it's not working
[image]

[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the existing [Elasticsearch adapter](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/elasticsearch_adapter.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DBeaver documentation](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Database-drivers) describes how to add a new database driver. You can specify whatever parameters you need as well as provide a Calcite JAR file so the necessary code is available.

The class name should be `org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver`. The URL Template will be something like `jdbc:calcite:model=path/to/model.json` where you specify a path to a `model.json` file which contains the necessary model to create the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but it s not working on Dbeaver. Do I need to use a jar?

Comment: @O.Sam Yes. As I mentioned in my answer, you will need to provide the Calcite JAR file. In general, if something is *not working*, providing some details of the problem you are experiencing is necessary to provide additional assistance.

Comment: I edited my question with the current configuration and the occuring error.

Comment: @O.Sam As the error message states, you are missing required JAR files. You need to add the `calcite-core` jar and whatever other related JARs for any adapters you are using. The `sqllineClasspath` JAR does not contain any relevant code.

Comment: I added `calcite-core` jar which generate two classes `org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver` and `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDriver`, I had the same error with both of them

Comment: thanks fr your help, I want to connect my new data source in Tableau through JDBC connection. I created an other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499567/connect-calcite-jdbc-connector-in-tableau-software