# Connect Calcite JDBC Connector in Tableau Software

Tags: jdbc, tableau-desktop, apache-calcite

I developed a custom connector for Elasticsearch with Apache Calcite.

I could connect to the datasource with Dbeaver SQL Client.

Now I want to use it as data source in Tableau Software. How should I configure it in Tableau,

This is how it's configured in Dbeaver: the idea is to do the same thing in Tableau
[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago, I logged a Calcite case ([[CALCITE-4859]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-4859)) for a Tableau connector and started work on it. It isn't yet complete, but there is a development branch and you're welcome to contribute to the effort.